# want a ImageView to come from upside down

Tags: android

i have a window and a imageview in it and i want the `imageview` to come from upside down animated effect how i do that

```
ImageView img_sliding=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_sliding);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write your own translate animation. a very good tutorial could be found [here.](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=343).

Here is a litte snipped that you can use and adapt it to your needs:

```
<translate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromYDelta="100%"
    android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="300"
    android:zAdjustment="top"
    android:fillAfter="true" />
```

create a new xml file in res/anim and then set the animation to your imageview like this:

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.YOURANIMATION)
```

and set it to the iamgeView

> imageview.setAnimation(anim);

Comment: this is the answer but in last the view is stopping for some time

Answer (score 0):

Use a scale animation to scale from -1 to 1. This should have the effect of flipping the imageview